# Como otimizar imagens?

Tags: imagem, otimização, pagespeed-insights

Eu estava seguindo alguns conselhos do PageSpeed Insights da Google e um deles é:

> Formatar e compactar corretamente imagens pode economizar muitos bytes de dados.

Entretanto eu já otimizei elas com um programa - [JpegMini](http://www.jpegmini.com/) - e mesmo assim ainda permanece a sugestão de otimizar as imagens (mesmo após os 30 segundos). Existe alguma outra maneira de otimizá-las?

Comment: Link relevante: [Otimização](http://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/miscelanea/como-otimizar-imagens-web-internet/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OptiPNG`:

```
$ optipng /tmp/saturno.png
** Processing: /tmp/saturno.png
1041x1041 pixels, 8 bits/pixel, 195 colors in palette
Input IDAT size = 119947 bytes
Input file size = 120793 bytes

Trying:
  zc = 9  zm = 8  zs = 0  f = 0     IDAT size = 118148
  zc = 9  zm = 8  zs = 1  f = 5     IDAT size = 113455
  zc = 9  zm = 8  zs = 3  f = 5     IDAT size = 112036

Selecting parameters:
  zc = 9  zm = 8  zs = 3  f = 5     IDAT size = 112036

Output IDAT size = 112036 bytes (7911 bytes decrease)
Output file size = 112846 bytes (7947 bytes = 6.58% decrease)
```

`jpegoptim`:

```
$ jpegoptim /tmp/jupiter.jpg 
/tmp/jupiter.jpg 1920x1080 24bit N Exif IPTC XMP ICC Adobe  [OK] 175249 --> 174634 bytes (0.35%), optimized.
```

Fontes: Imagem [JPG](https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/vis/a010000/a011900/a011921/c-1920.jpg) e [PNG](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/full_width_feature/public/thumbnails/image/pia01969-saturn-voyager1.png)

Answer (score 1):

### Imagemin

Uma alternativa seria o **imagemin**, via terminal usando o [imagemin-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin-cli) ou se preferirem via aplicação [imagemin-app](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-app), mas esta última não funciona tão bem (pelo a versão testado). Existe também a possibilidade via [Grunt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-imagemin) ou [Gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-imagemin).

No caso se usar via terminal `imagemin-cli`:

```
# instalar o imagemin via npm
npm install -g imagemin-cli

# optimizar todas as imagens JPG/PNG/SVG de uma pasta
imagemin pasta_com_images/* -o pasta_de_destino/
```

Utilizando as imagens de referência (ver abaixo) para comparação verifica-se que:

- `c-1920.jpg` teve uma redução de **6,7%**
- `pia01969-saturn-voyager1.png` teve uma redução de **11,8%**

### ImageOptim

Outra alternativa apenas para imagens bitmap, seria o **ImageOptim**, via terminal usando o [Imageoptim-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imageoptim-cli) ou se preferirem via aplicação [imageoptim para MAC OS](https://imageoptim.com/mac), ou para [outras plataformas](https://imageoptim.com/versions.html). Existe também a possibilidade via [Grunt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-imageoptim) ou [Gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-imageoptim).

No caso se usar via terminal `imageoptim-cli`:

```
# instalar via npm
npm install -g imageoptim-cli

# optimizar todas as imagens JPG/PNG de uma pasta
imageoptim -d ./pasta_com_images/
```

Utilizando as imagens de referência para comparação verifica-se que:

- `c-1920.jpg` teve uma redução de **21,1%**
- `pia01969-saturn-voyager1.png` teve uma redução de **10,7%**

### Resumo

Por esta pequena experiência o ImageOptim reduziu consideravelmente mais a imagem JPEG do que o Imagemin (21,1% em vez dos 6,7%). Já a imagem PNG foram próximas, obtendo o imagemin melhor redução (11,8% em vez dos 10,7% do ImageOptim). Por outro lado o imagemin optimiza também imagens SVG.

Para a comparação efetuada foi utilizando as imagens fonte [JPG](https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/vis/a010000/a011900/a011921/c-1920.jpg) e [PNG](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/full_width_feature/public/thumbnails/image/pia01969-saturn-voyager1.png) utilizados na resposta do Lacobus.

Para outros exemplos ver a seguinte [comparação](https://jamiemason.github.io/ImageOptim-CLI/comparison/gif/photoshop/desc/)

Espero que ajude alguém!